# Creating new object from method argument or referencing instead

Tags: java

```
public setArrayList(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;

    //OR

    this.list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
}
```

I have seen different people use this code interchangeably. Is there a difference between these two implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the two examples are functionally different.

```
public setArrayList(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

This assigns the `list` member of the current class to the *same object instance* as the list that is passed in. Adding and removing elements to/from the list will affect the original list.

```
this.list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
```

This creates a *new instance* of the list, copying the elements from the original one. Adding and removing elements from this new list will not affect the original list.

Comment: So if I say `this.list = list`, and then I modify `this.list`, it will alter `list`?

Comment: Yes, it will. That is, adding and removing elements will affect `list`. If you assign a *new* list to `list` after this point, they will become independent as the reference held in the variable now points to a new object.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
this.list = list;
```

does not create anything (or, rather, it creates a copy of the value of the reference held by the parameter `list`). It assigns a value to a variable.

This

```
this.list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
```

invokes [the constructor of `ArrayList` passing a value of type `List` as an argument.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) The resulting value of the constructor invocation is then assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference between these two implementations?

Yes, there is a difference. In the first example (`this.list = list;`) this Object has a reference to the same `List` as the caller. In the second example, a new List is created. This list is independent of the caller. Consider,

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
Foo f = new Foo();
f.setArrayList(al);
al.clear(); // <-- the first example would empty f's list, the second wouldn't.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,These both have a difference.
In First one Rather then creating new object of list it will took reference of the object.So whenever list get changed it changes in passed list too.
In Second one it has created new object so if we modify(Add/Remove element) this.list then it will not affect on argument.